# How would current flow in a resistor in this case?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

Suppose I have a power supply and wire with zero resistance, what would happen if I connect a resistor in series to the circuit creating a short? All the voltage would drop in the resistor and thus no current will flow in the circuit? Of course it's a non real world example.

Comment: If there is a voltage drop in the resistor, then there is current flow. Ohm's Law still applies.

Comment: Ohms Law.......  The amount of resistance in the wire and resistor will dictate the current flowing through the circuit.

Comment: Voltage will not drop in the resistor, it is the potential across it. Ohms law says the current = voltage/resistance, and that rule applies in spite of the rest of the circuit (including the power supply internal resistance).

Comment: I = V/R and if voltage is zero and resistance is zero, I = 0/0 i.e. you can't state what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Some find it easier to understand electronics using physical world metaphors:

- Consider the voltage source as a water pump which produces 9 pounds per square inch pressure.
- Consider the wires as pipes.
- Consider the resistor as a constriction in the pipe.

At every point between the high pressure side of the water pump and the constriction, the pressure is 9 pounds per square inch.  After the constriction the water pressure drops to zero and the water is free to flow back to the water pump.

Note:  Even though all the pressure drops across the restriction, the water still flows!

So, in this metaphor:

1. The water pressure is the voltage (V).
2. The water flow is the current (I).
3. The constriction in the pipe is the resistance (R).

A useful relationship between these are:

> V = I x R

...to solve for values other than V just rearrange the equation to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Y7Ur.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming you use the above circuit, the current through the resistor will be 9V/1KOhm = 9mA according to Ohm's law. No current will flow if either the source produces 0V or if the resistor would have an infinite resistance (i.e. an open circuit).